# How to SELECT vertices of class a connected to vertices of class b, based on name of b

Tags: select, orientdb, vertex

In OrientDB-Studio:

1.) SELECT * from pinkclass

2.) Expand greyclass by double click on each pinkclass vertex

In the resulting picture below, only three greyclass vertices are connected to each significant vertices of pinkclass.

My Question:

How to query vertices of greyclass connected to each vertex pinkclass, based on the name of vertex pinkclass?

Or

How to query the vertices in the red circle by the name of the pink vertices?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select from greyclass where in().name contains "<pinkclass vertex name>" and in().name contains "<pinkclass vertex name>" and in().name contains "<pinkclass vertex name>" and in().name contains "<pinkclass vertex name>" and in().name contains "<pinkclass vertex name>" and in().name contains "<pinkclass vertex name>"
```